# Microsoft Azure blocking server?

Tags: azure

Is possible, that MS is blocking server (vm) for few days, without some response why they did it? I am playing on one sever, which has server in azure, server is off 5-6 days and they said, it's because MS is blocking their server and they are waiting for response. I think it's bullshit, right?

Comment: The only way to know is to speak to Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by blocking server, and who is 'they' who is telling you this?  MS doesn't 'block' servers unless you are on a trial account and have hit your spending cap for the free trial at which time the VM will be shut down but the VHD will still exist in storage.